# C++- My Password Program is not changing Password

Tags: c++, string, passwords

I have created a program that get password from user. User can also change the password by saving the original password in a string and then the old password in a new string but if both are matched the user can enter the new password but even if I enter same password in both new and old strings the if statement is not returning true and password is not changed.
2nd, when I enter password and press enter key, enter is also stored in password.
Here is my code

```
void password(int n)
{
    string pass = "0", oldpass = "0";
    char ch = '0';
    if (n)
    {
        cout << "Enter Old Password: ";
        ch = _getch();
        while (ch != '\r')
        {
            oldpass.push_back(ch);
            cout << "*";
            ch = _getch();
        }
        cout << "Password is " << oldpass << endl;
        if (oldpass == pass)
        {
            cout << "Enter New Password: ";
            ch = _getch();
            while (ch != '\r')
            {
                pass.push_back(ch);
                cout << "*";
                ch = _getch();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nPassword Does Not Match" << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No Password Found. Enter New Password... ";
        ch = _getch();
        while (ch != '\r')
        {
            pass.push_back(ch);
            cout << "*";
            ch = _getch();
        }
        cout << "Password is " << pass<<endl;
        cout << "\nPassword Saved Successfully" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter is not being stored in your password.

Your default initialization of "0" is, and will eventually be throwing you off. Start with empty strings.

Also you never reset the value of either passwords, both are being appended with every call using  string.push_back(char). And remember that the variables in functions do not persist, so every call thereafter to the function will have defaulted the variables to their initialized values.

A good debug approach would be to display the values of both strings, when prompting for the old password; you will see that every call to the function defaults both strings to "0", and that if you're using a loop within the functions, every cycle will append more characters on to the string rather than overwriting the strings with the strings you're expecting.

Basically, at some point, either before or after the assignments of either string, you will have to erase the previous values in the strings, before reusing them.

Comment: Got it Thanks a lot. Just one thing does declaring a string and not initializing it, makes it an empty string. I thought it got a garbage value??

Comment: String isn't a primitive data type: int, float, double, char, etc. String is a class and handles the exceptions that c-style strings do not. So no, if you do not initialize a String object, it will set it's default size count to 0, will not contain any characters, and will handle calls to itself. Whereas c-style strings, are an array of characters, and will have set memory of characters equal to it's size regardless if the memory initialized or not.

Comment: Ok I Understand and what you said about everycall of pushback function??

Comment: Using String.push_back(char) appends characters to the end of the string. After verifying the old password, you try to create a new password, by appending more characters to the string... You should assign the string pass "" or call pass.clear() before appending the pass string again.

Comment: Yes I have done all of this thanks for help,, Can you help me in another problem?? I am making a shopping mall database but don't know how to do file handling.